# Python - Run function with parameters in command line

Tags: python, command-line

Is it possible to run a python script with parameters in command line like this:

```
./hello(var=True)
```

or is it mandatory to do like this:

```
python -c "from hello import *;hello(var=True)"
```

The first way is shorter and simpler.

Comment: [CLI arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Comment: The mere fact that you have `sys.argv` (pretty much the same idea that is behind the `int argc, char *[]argv` in C/C++) should tell you that it's possible. However the way you're doing it is incorrect. Check the link @ViacheslavKondratiuk sent you plus the official documentation. Also note that you can [`getopt()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) which is a C-style CLI argument parser. There are other modules for this too but these two are omho the usual pick.

Comment: Can you call it without `python -c`? Yes. With the syntax you propose? No.

Comment: I would like to indicate to the user the number of arguments to provide like this: hello(var1=false,var2=false,var3...). If I use the syntax: python hello.py arg1 arg2, the user doesn't know the number of arguments to provide.

Comment: If your users are unfamiliar with the CLI, either: 1. explain it to them; or 2. provide a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

Most shells use parentheses for grouping or sub-shells. So you can't call any commands like `command(arg)` from a normal shell ...but you can write a python script (./hello.py) that takes an argument.

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-f', dest="f", action="store_true", default=False)
options, remainder = parser.parse_args()
print ("Flag={}".format(options.f))
```

And the call it with `python hello.py -f`

Answer (score 0):

`./hello(var=True)` would be impossible from [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) shell. In some case it could be useful to have python function available in your current shell session. Here a workaround to make your python functions available in your shell environment.

```
# python-tools.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -a # make all available export all variable)

function hello(){
    cd "/app/python/commands"
    python "test.py" $@
}
```

Content of the python script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# /app/python/commands/test.py script

import sys


def test(*args):
    print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if sys.argv[1] in globals().keys():
        print(sys.argv[1])
        globals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2:])
    else:
        print("%s Not known function" % sys.argv[1])
```

Then source python-tools.sh

```
source python-tools.sh
```

After the hello function is available

```
$ hello test arg2 arg2
test
(['arg2', 'arg2'],)
```